# Why generating react components from list from parent state prevents components from rerendering on parent state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered a problem and I have no idea why the problem occurred in this situation.
I created a simple App with just two components:

App.js

```
import ParentComponent from './parentComponent';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <ParentComponent/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

parentComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './childComponent';

class ParentComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            elemsList: [],
            valueToDisplayInChild: 'Hello World!'
        };

        this.setValueToDisplayInChild = this.setValueToDisplayInChild.bind(this);
        this.changeValueToDisplay = this.changeValueToDisplay.bind(this);
    }

    setElemsList(elemsList) {
        this.setState({
            elemsList
        })
    }

    setValueToDisplayInChild(valueToDisplayInChild) {
        this.setState({
            valueToDisplayInChild
        })
    }

    changeValueToDisplay() {
        this.setValueToDisplayInChild('Bye World!');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setElemsList([<ChildComponent key='key' value={this.state.valueToDisplayInChild} />]);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.elemsList}
                <button onClick={this.changeValueToDisplay}>
                    Button
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default ParentComponent;
```

childComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>{this.props.value}</p>
        );
    }
}


export default ChildComponent;
```

When I click that button in the `ParentComponent` then its state changes but `ChildComponet` stays with "Hello World!". I can just put `<ChildComponent key='key' value={this.state.valueToDisplayInChild} />]` directly into `render()` return and then updating works fine but I'm curious about the reason why the above approach fails.

P.S.
I'm a React newbie so maybe it's just me not understanding react components lifecycles.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: componentDidMount works only one time when the component is mounted in dom.

Comment: Yes, but `valueToDisplayInChild` changes on a click. Shouldn't that trigger rerendering `ChildComponent` as its props changes?

Comment: But ChidlComponent will be rendered only once on componentDidMount. Moving it to render function of Parent will cause rendering Child too.

Comment: But my main question is why changing props of the `ChildComponent` doesn't trigger rerending. Isn't it the way react rending works?